# Finding whether a set of continuous functions is open or closed.

Tags: analysis, functions, metric-spaces

Am really struggling to get to grips of the concept of open and closed sets when the elements of the set are functions. 
If considering the set of continuous functions that map $(0,1)$ onto $\Bbb R$ for example, how would I identify whether this is a closed or open set. I understand the definitions of closed and open sets in terms of balls, but am struggling to apply this to a set of functions. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a metric on the set of functions that you are interested in?

Comment: I'll add to @MeesdeVries comment that there are many natural distances on the set of functions. So unless you tell us in which you are interested we're unable to answer this question.

Comment: Yes, in particular the metric d(f,g) = sup (of x belonging to X) dY(f(x),g(x)).  Where f,g, maps (X, dx) onto (Y,dy)

Comment: Alright. Then a second thing we definitely need is a contextual set. A set $A$ cannot be open or closed by itself; it needs to be open or closed as a subset $A \subseteq X$ of a metric (or topological) space $X$.